# Automatically resize columns height on hide/show divs (part 2)

Tags: jquery

I'd like to automatically resize the height of my 2 columns (sameht) when I hide some divs by toggle function (or hide/show).

```
<div class="span2 sameht">
  <div class="content">
     <div class="hidelevel">something</div>
     <div>something</div>
     <div>something</div>
     <div>something</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="span3 sameht">
  <div class="content">
     <div>something</div>
     <div>something</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- how it should be sameht after hide divs-->

<div class="span2 sameht2">
  <div class="content">
      <div>something</div>
      <div>something</div>
      <div>something</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="span3 sameht2">
   <div class="content">
      <div>something</div>
      <div>something</div>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- toggle -->

<div id="toggle">Toogle Visibility sameht</div>
```

to have the same height for the columns I used this code

```
$( function() {
   adjustHeight();
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $(".hidelevel").toggle();
        adjustHeight();
    });
});

function adjustHeight(){
var maxHeight = 0
    $('.sameht').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
});
$('.sameht').height(maxHeight);
}

var maxHeight = 0
$('.sameht2').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
});
$('.sameht2').height(maxHeight);
```

When I hide the divs (.hidelevel) and call adjustHeight function the "sameht" columns not resize the height of the columns (see sameht2 how it should be).

Have you any idea how can I do this? Thanks.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jXgLd/33/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$('.sameht2').css('height','500px');
```

to get the result you desire.

JD

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't my problem! sameht2 is the right result aspect, I don't want change it! I think you don't understand my question..